# Create SOAP request with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, soap, wsdl, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to call a webservice in vb.net and I have followed this thread: [WebService Send SOAP request and received response using visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136293/webservice-send-soap-request-and-received-response-using-visual-basic)

These are the steps that I have followed:

1. I have already add the reference to the project (http://webservice_url?wsdl).
2. I have written the soap request in an xml file by hand ([I attach the xml file as image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5pZu.png) )
3. I have load the xml file into an string variable and call to the webservice like that:

   ```
       Dim strDocumentoSoap As String
       Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\myFile.xml")
       strDocumentoSoap = document.ToString


       Dim servicioWeb As svc.v79jIntegracionPerfilSesion = New svc.v79jIntegracionPerfilSesion
       Dim sbLogin As New System.Text.StringBuilder
       sbLogin.Append(strDocumentoSoap)

       Dim hwrequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
       hwrequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://myServiceURL/realizarPeticionPublicacionOSBUS?WSDL")
       hwrequest.Method = "POST"
       hwrequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
       Dim byteData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbLogin.ToString())
       hwrequest.ContentLength = byteData.Length

       Dim writer As Stream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream
       writer.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
       writer.Close()
       Dim Response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
       Response = hwrequest.GetResponse
       Dim responseStatus As String = Response.StatusDescription.ToString
       Dim DataStream As Stream
       Dim Reader As StreamReader

       DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream()
       Reader = New StreamReader(DataStream)
       Dim SD2Request As String = Reader.ReadToEnd()
       'SHOW THE RESPONSE INTO MSGBOX
       MsgBox(SD2Request)
   ```

This works perfectly, but I have read in the internet that this practice is not recommended (hand made XML for SOAP), because there are other useful tools in .net.

Can anyone explain me other options or libraries for creating a soap request in VB.NET without creating the soapenvelope by hand.

Thank you very much in advance!

Marga